# how to read files from Internal Storage

Tags: java, android

Iam new to android programming 
this code is giving FilenotFound Exception
and going through catch block
where should i save my .txt file.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myCOde=findViewById(R.id.code);
    String filename="bully rap.txt";
    try {
        readCode(filename);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        myCOde.setText("file not found");
    }
}



    private void readCode(String filename) throws Exception{
    File filesDir=MainActivity.this.getFilesDir();
    File myFile=new File(filesDir,filename);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));

    String st;
    StringBuilder code= new StringBuilder("hello");
    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null){
     code.append(st);
     myCOde.setText(code);
    }
```

Comment: Where is the file you want to be read is located?

Comment: in phones Internal Storage download folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below code is not gonna help you to achieve what you want.

```
File filesDir = MainActivity.this.getFilesDir();
```

Above code usually returns the path where `/data/data/{your package name}/files`. If you want to access an external file directory, as in you case like **Download** folder you should use something like below.

```
String filesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

Furthermore if you are going to write to an external file directory, you may need to add neccessary permissions in the manifest.xml